# Can I stub "raise" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, testing, exception, rspec

I have a class called `RemoteError` with a `self.fatal` method on it. This methods job is basically to catch an exception, send the details of the exception to a server and then propagate the exception in order to kill the program.

```
class RemoteError
  def initialize(label, error)
    @label = label
    @error = error
  end

  def self.fatal(label, error)
    object = new(label, error)
    object.send
    raise error
  end

  def send
    # send the error to the server
  end
end
```

I'm trying to write tests for the `RemoteError.fatal` method. This is difficult because of the call to `raise` within the method. Every time I run my tests, `raise` obviously raises an exception and I can't test that `send` was called.

```
  describe "fatal" do
    it "should send a remote error" do
      error = stub
      RemoteError.stub(:new) { error }
      error.should_receive(:send)

      RemoteError.fatal(stub, stub)
    end
  end
```

Is there a way that I can stub or somehow circumvent `raise` for this specific test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could wrap the method that raises the error in a lambda...

```
it "should send a remote error" do
  ...

  lambda { RemoteError.fatal(stub, stub) }.should raise_error(error)
end
```

This essentially allows the method to be called, and you get the return value or raised error from it, which you then assert against with `.should raise_error(error)`. This also makes is so that if **no error** is raised from that call, the test will fail normally.

To say it another way, you don't need, nor want, to stub `raise`. Simply wrap it in a lambda and your code will continue to execute, you should be able to make sure that your message is sent, and your test won't exit/crash.

Comment: You could also use the `expect { }.to raise_error` form, which is a little easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

In your tests you are testing the method that raises an error and this is an expected result of method execution. You should write expectation for exception with this syntax:

```
lambda{ RemoteError.fatal(stub, stub) }.should raise_error
```

In this case your spec will fail if exception won't be raised and also will fail if all other expectations (like `should_receive(:sen)`) won't be met.